# Make reindent work in sublime text 3 aside Doc block

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, auto-indent

I explain.

I use Sublime Text 3.
In a js file, when i call reindent on it, all my code get the good indentation.
But there is bug if a fonction is after a doc block (for js doc). If there is this doc block, my function get indentation with +1 space, because of the indent +1 space position of the '*' the doc block.

How can i remove this "falsy" behaviour and hoave the right reindent

i have :

```
    ..../**
         * @desc the basic toggle function to display/hide an element
    .....* @param target css selector of the target
         */
    .....self.toggle= function(event, target){
            $(target).toggle();
         };
```

and want

```
    ..../**
         * @desc the basic toggle function to display/hide an element
    .....* @param target css selector of the target
         */
    ....self.toggle= function(event, target){
            $(target).toggle();
        };
```

---

## **SOLUTION** :

install the JSFormat package for sublime

and use this key binding to make it work everywhere

```
[
{ 
    "keys": ["control+shift+i"], 
    "command": "js_format", 
    "context": {
        "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.coffeescript"
    }
},
{ 
    "keys": ["control+shift+i"], 
    "command": "reindent", 
    "context": {
        "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "source.coffeescript"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: I would take a look at the JSFormat package of sublime

Comment: thanks, i got it worked
i update le topic with my solution